# The fundamental theorem of calculus for a continuous function in R

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Checking answers for an exam I have met the following statement:
real function $f$ is continuous in $\Bbb R$, therefore following the fundamental theorem of calculus its proceed that :

for: $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$

we get:

$\\F'(x) = f(x)$

Now, for each $x \ge 0  $ I of course can understand why it is true, but for $x<0$ I can't see why and fail to prove it by myself, and humbly ask for an explanation.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $x\ge a$ and $x<a$?

Comment: I miswrote, now it is fixed

Comment: Can you write down the proof for $x\ge 0$ and explain to us why you fail to see how it works for $x<0$?

Comment: for $x>=0$ it is following the theorem, but for $x<0$ it doesn't

Comment: For $x<0$ you need to transform the integral using $\int_{a}^{b}=-\int_{b}^{a}$, then adapt the usual proof.

Comment: I have tried, fail to prove it

Comment: @YotamBerlinsky The definition of $\int_0^x$, if $x$ is negative, is that it is equal to $-\int_x^0$.